# SQL - How to get the count of each value with condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables

```
**room**
    room_id | nurse_needed
    ----------------------
    1       | 3
    2       | 1
    3       | 2


**doctor_schedule**
    doctor_schedule_id| room_id | date     |shift
    -------------------------------------------------
           1          | 1       |12-30-2016|   1
           2          | 2       |12-31-2016|   2
           3          | 3       |12-30-2016|   2
           4          | 2       |12-30-2016|   2
*nurse_schedule*
    nurse_schedule_id | doctor_schedule_id
    --------------------------------------
    1                 |         1         
    2                 |         1         
    3                 |         3 
    4                 |         4
```

There are 8 shift per day. Each shift have one doctor and in each shift need a number of nurse.Nurses work with doctor's schedule. I ONLY want to count how many shift don't have enough nurse in `12-30-2016`. My function is: `get_shift_need_nurse(String date){}` The result should be:

```
    doctor_schedule_id| room_id | date     |shift | nurse_needed|nurse_have_in_room
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           1          | 1       |12-30-2016|   1  |     3       |    2
           3          | 3       |12-30-2016|   2  |     2       |    1
```

Because in `12-30-2016` shift number 1 and shift number 2 don't have enough nurse in each room. `doctor_schedule_id =4` is not result, it had enough nurse in `nurse_schedule_id =4`

Answer (score 0):

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN nurse_needed = nurse_have_in_room then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "HasEnoughNurses"
```

Answer (score 0):

**SQL:**

```
Select d.DOCTOR_SCHEDULE_ID, d.ROOM_ID, d.DT, d.SHIFT, r.ROOM_ID, r.NURSE_NEEDED, Count(*) nurse_have_in_room
  From doctor_schedule d
       Join room r on d.room_id = r.room_id
       Join nurse_schedule n On d.doctor_schedule_id = n.doctor_schedule_id
    Group by d.DOCTOR_SCHEDULE_ID, d.ROOM_ID, d.DT, d.SHIFT, r.ROOM_ID, r.NURSE_NEEDED
    Having Count(*) < r.NURSE_NEEDED
```

**test result:**

```
1   3   3   12-30-2016  2   3   2   1
2   1   1   12-30-2016  1   1   3   2
```

Comment: But when table `nurse_schedule` null, your query don't show any `DOCTOR_SCHEDULE` record need more nurse